# angular 2 dynamically added panels not collapsing/expanding

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, observable

I have a fragment of HTML, representing a collapsible panel that expands/collapses as expected but when I use that same piece of markup within an Angular 2 Observable, *ngFor, the expand/collapse behaviour is lost.  I can see the 'content' of the panel within the source but the panel starts and remains collapsed.

```
<app-tab>    
  <app-tab-item *ngFor="let query of queries$ | async" [title]="query.name">
    <div>
      <div class="ibox collapsed">
        <div class="ibox-title">
          <h5>Collapsed Panel within Observable</h5>
          <div class="ibox-tools">
            <a class="collapse-link">
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content" style="display: none;">
          <p>Collapsed panel within observable</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </app-tab-item>

  <app-tab-item title="This Works!">
    <div>
      <div class="ibox collapsed">
        <div class="ibox-title">
          <h5>Collapsed Panel</h5>
          <div class="ibox-tools">
            <a class="collapse-link">
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content" style="display: none;">
          <p>Collapsed panel</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </app-tab-item>

</app-tab>
```